# Active download does not supersede suspend

Tags: software-installation, suspend, downloads

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

My system is set to suspend after 10 minutes of idle time. I like this, but if I have a download going, the system will go into suspend anyway and the download will pause.

If I want to start a big download and go AFK for a while, do I really have to go into the power settings and disable suspend? This doesn't seem like it should be necessary. Surely, Ubuntu is supposed to prevent automatic suspension, or continue the download in the background, while the system is suspended.

This happens with Firefox, Chromium, and Synaptic Package Manager. I haven't tried to replicate this problem with other applications that include a download function, but those three are the ones I use the most.

Is there a way to fix this?

Also, I'm worried that if I was to be installing a big package and went AFK for >10 minutes, that process would get suspended too, and damage the installation.

Comment: When I use a Download manager/torrent client, they include this option, I'm not sure that Firefox/Chrome/ium would.

Comment: See this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/576525/can-i-prevent-ubuntu-being-suspended-while-a-download-is-in-progress) question. You can use the script provided there to supersede suspend while any upload or download in progress. Change wlan0 to eth0 or use both if its applies.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a Suspended System only preserves your RAM data,***would not continue*** processing because thats what suspending means.

***So no way of continuing download if system is on suspend mode.***

What can be done is:

1. Disable suspend  (System settings->Power->Don't suspend when inactive for)
2. Just lock screen(Ctrl+Alt+L) if you go off the system.
3. System continues to process whatever it's set for.

**NOTE:** You need to change POWER SETTINGS only if you put system on suspend(while inactive).